# How to call QTimer from other class n Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtimer

I am using an QML in Qt.
Having two classes, 
Board class and TimerUi class.

1. QML calls the Board::start()
2. The Board::start() calls the TimerUi::startTimer().

The problem is, QTimer in TimerUi class does not start at all. The main thing i wanted, is to leave all timer based functions in one place, and have ability to call it from any class.

If i call the TimerUi::startTimer() directly from QML - it works.

Can someone explain me please, where is my error?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QString>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "board.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Test");
  QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("test");
  QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Test");

  qmlRegisterType<Board>("io.qt.board", 1, 0, "Board");

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.9
import io.qt.board 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtWebEngine 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    // Init Board 
    Board {id: board}

    // Init
    Component.onCompleted: {
        board.init();
    }

    RoundButton {
        id: startButton
        x: 14
        y: 26
        width: 230
        height: 230
        text: !board.isStarted ? "Start" : "Stop"
        font.pointSize: 30
        background: Image { source: board.isStarted? "/stop.png" : "/start.png"; }
        onClicked: board.start()

        contentItem: Text {

            text: startButton.text
            font: startButton.font
            opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
            color: "black"
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

        }
    }


}
```

**board.h**

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QTimer>

class Board : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_PROPERTY(bool isStarted READ isStarted NOTIFY isStartedChanged WRITE
                 setIsStarted) 

public:
  explicit Board(QObject *parent = nullptr);

  bool isStarted();

  Q_INVOKABLE void init();
  Q_INVOKABLE void start();

signals:
  void isStartedChanged(bool b_isStarted);

public slots:

private:
  QString b_start;
  static bool b_isStarted;
};

#endif // BOARD_H
```

**board.cpp**

```
#include "board.h"
#include "timerui.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QTimer>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool Board::b_isStarted = 0;

bool Board::isStarted() { return b_isStarted; }

void Board::setIsStarted(bool &isStarted) {
  b_isStarted = isStarted;
  emit isStartedChanged(isStarted);
}

Board::Board(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

void Board::init() {
  qDebug() << "Some init";
}

// Start
void Board::start() {

  TimerUi timerUi;

  if (!b_isStarted) {

    qDebug() << "isStarted";

    b_isStarted = true;

    timerUi.startTimer(); // <-- Here
  }

  emit isStartedChanged(b_isStarted);
}
```

**timerui.h**

```
#ifndef TIMERUI_H
#define TIMERUI_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QTimer>

class TimerUi : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QTimer *m_timer;
  Q_PROPERTY(int minTimer READ minTimer NOTIFY minTimerChanged())

public:
  explicit TimerUi(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  Q_INVOKABLE void startTimer(QObject *target);
  int minTimer();

signals:
  void minTimerChanged();

public slots:
  void setTime();

private:
  static int m_minTimer;
};

#endif // TIMERUI_H
```

**timer.cpp**

```
#include "timerui.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QTimer>

int TimerUi::m_minTimer = 0;

TimerUi::TimerUi(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

int TimerUi::minTimer() { return m_minTimer; }

void TimerUi::startTimer() {

  m_minTimer = 0;

  // Timer
  QTimer *m_timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(setTime()));
  m_timer->start(1000);
}

void TimerUi::setTime() {

    minTimer++;
    qDebug() << "Hello " << minTimer;

  emit minTimerChanged();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: We need a lot more details.  Please produce an [S.S.C.C.E](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Please provide your code instead of explaining it.

Comment: I suspect the usual error happened, you are referring to two different instance, but without code... not much we can say

Comment: move `TimerUi timerUi;` to `private:` section

Comment: If i move it to private section, it crashes on the connect

Comment: Ok, i managed it to work, moved to private, and changed   QTimer m_timer{this}; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You declare your TimerUI in the local scope of Board::start, it is destroyed when the function end. That is probably where your problem come from.

Comment: Can you provide an example please, on how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Well I can't decide for you what you want to achieve, but from what I understand i think that your timerUi variable should simply be declared as a member of your class Board.